# @change event is not firing with rangeslider.js in vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, rangeslider

I'm using rangeslider.js plugin for a custom slider. In vue 3, while I slide/change the the slider value @change event is not firing. How to solve this issue.

HTML:

```js
data(){
    return{
                
        }
    },
    methods:{

        updateChart(chartId, point){
                //will do something
        }
    },
    created(){
            
    },
    mounted(){
            
            
    }
```

```html
<input
    type="range"
    min="0"
    max="10"
    name="rating"
    id="rating"
    step="1"
    data-ratingslider="true"
    value="0"
    autocomplete="off"
    @change="updateChart(rating)"
/>
```

I've tested "ng-change" event in angularjs with rangeslider.js which working fine. What's wrong about vue3 ?

Comment: First, it's a bad idea to use a vanilla JS library like this which directly manipulates the DOM and requires the use of JQuery. There's many other Vue-specific thid party slider components you could use instead. Second, you _can_ get this library working in Vue, but you've not shown how you've installed OR initialized it. Of course the event won't fire if you've not initialized rangeslider with your input element... That is to say, you've not given enough details to prove the problem is actually related to the change event. Right now, we must assume the usage is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

applying event dispatch has solved the issue for me.

```
data(){
return{
            
    }
},
methods:{

    updateChart(chartId, point){
            //will do something
    },
    eventDispatch(element, event) {
            element.dispatchEvent(new Event(event));
    }
},
created(){
        
},
mounted(){
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="range"]', function(e) {
            _this.slideRatingValue = e.target.value;
            _this.eventDispatch(e.target, e.handleObj.type);
        });         
}
```

}